# El widget Select2 de Yii2 no borra la selección anterior

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

Que tal buenos días. Tengo este detalle al seleccionar opciones de una lista con Select2 de Yii2, por ejemplo tomo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se guarda la modificación y trato de hacer lo mismo con otro salón de clases para asignarle un maestro de secundaria, pero me manda el mismo maestro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en dado caso que también le toque darle clases a ese salón doy clic pero no hace nada hasta que selecciono un maestro diferente. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que en primera instancia este en blanco la lista o tenga el placeholder que escribí?

Este es el código:

```
<?php echo Select2::widget([
'name' => 'listaMaestros',
'model' => '',
'attribute' => 'listaMaestros',
'data' => $modelM ,
'options' => [
    'placeholder' => 'Elegir maestro',
    'id' => 'eleccionMaestros',
    'class'=>'eleccionMaestrosC',
    'data-id_maestro' => ''
],]);?>
```

Comment: No usas un _form para capturar el valor seleccionado ? Podrias mostrar la vista o formulario en su totalidad?